# Microsoft .NET namespace casing convention

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces

I was in the process of adding a reference to a dll when I noticed that the vast majority instances of the Microsoft namespace has a uppercase M and on rare occasions they have a lower case m.

[image]

Is there a reason or any logic for this?

Does anyone know the reasoning for this decision by Microsoft?

Comment: Looks like an oversight to me, StyleCop/FxCop should flag up things like that.

Comment: Nice observation Nicholas.

Comment: [msxml](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSXML#Obsolete) has been around since 1997/IE4.0. Perhaps it's lower case out of legacy/compatibility for some reason. (of course `Microsoft.mshtml`, which is the Trident layout engine, was introduced at the same time, but that's been given the upper-case treatment)

Comment: Do you have any examples of cases where the namespace has a lowercase M? This is purely out of interest, it's not something that I believe I've ever stumbled across.

Comment: @Xefan as per the screenshot I think there are 2 assemblies with lowercase m. Just scan down the microsoft .net assemblies namespace

Comment: Apologies, the screenshot hadn't loaded for me for some reason, that explains a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those entries you pointed out are not normal .NET framework assemblies.  And they are auto-generated by tooling.  Two good reasons they don't follow .NET framework naming conventions.  They are PIAs, Primary Interop Assemblies.  They contain the declarations retrieved from a COM component's type library, converted into .NET metadata to make it easy for the CLR to interop with the COM component.  The types in these PIAs have the [ComImport] attribute.

Tlbimp.exe is the tool used to auto-generate these assemblies, the `/primary` command line option generates a PIA.  The ones you got from Microsoft are slightly different from the ones you'll get when you run Tlbimp.exe yourself.  For one, Microsoft includes a version resource in the assembly.  For another, the names for these PIAs are not the default name that Tlbimp.exe generates.  So you are seeing what the build engineer at Microsoft typed for the `/out` command line option.  Clearly he's not paying much attention to casing.

Microsoft.msxml is the PIA for c:\windows\system32\msxml3.dll, very commonly used in older code to read and write XML documents.  Microsoft.mshtml is the PIA for c:\windows\system32\mshtml.tlb, the type library for the DOM interface supported by Internet Explorer and one you'll need when you want to dig through the HTML elements of a web page.  You can look at these type libraries in their "native" format with the Oleview.exe tool, File + View Typelib.  What you'll see otherwise looks very similar to what you'll see with Object Browser, except that they are expressed in IDL, Interface Description Language, the language that was originally used to generate these type libraries.

PIAs are mostly an historical artifact, the Embed Interop Type feature available since .NET 4 made them unnecessary.